# Emulating the camera apps 'tap to focus'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I am trying hard to emulate the basic functionality of the built in camera app. Thus far I have become stuck on the 'tap to focus' feature.

I have a UIView from which I am collecting UITouch events when a single finger is tapped on the UIView. This following method is called but the camera focus & the exposure are unchanged.

```
-(void)handleFocus:(UITouch*)touch
{ 
     if( [camera lockForConfiguration:nil] )
     {     
          CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:cameraView];

          if( [camera isFocusPointOfInterestSupported] )
               camera.focusPointOfInterest = location;

          if( [camera isExposurePointOfInterestSupported] )
               camera.exposurePointOfInterest = location;


          [camera unlockForConfiguration];
          [cameraView animFocus:location];
     }
}
```

'camera' is my AVCaptureDevice & it is non-nil. Can someone perhaps tell me where I am going wrong?

Clues & boos all welcome.

M.

Comment: Also remember that both exposurePointOfInterest and focusPointOfInterest are CGPoints between (0,0) and (1,1). Regardless of the device's orientation, (0,0) is the upper left hand corner and (1,1) is the lower right hand corder of the device in the Landscape Right orientation.  So using `camera.focusPointOfInterest = location` won't get you the results you want.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This snippet might help you...There is a CamDemo provided by apple floating around which allows you to focus, change exposure while tapping, set flash, swap cameras and more, it emulates the camera app pretty well, not sure if youll be able to find it since it was part of wwdc, but if u leave some email address in the comments i can email you the sample code...

```
- (void) focusAtPoint:(CGPoint)point

{

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self videoInput] device];

    if ([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported] && [device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus]) {

        NSError *error;

        if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error]) {

            [device setFocusPointOfInterest:point];

            [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];

            [device unlockForConfiguration];

        } else {

            id delegate = [self delegate];

            if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(acquiringDeviceLockFailedWithError:)]) {

                [delegate acquiringDeviceLockFailedWithError:error];

            }

        }        

    }

}
```

Comment: I'd be very glad for that source code. Catch me at codehammer <at> suremail <dot> info.

My thanks again.

Comment: @Martin Cowie - Actually, the source code is available as part of the WWDC 2010 videos.  Simply login to get the videos, go to iTunes, and a link to download the sample code will appear in the upper-right: http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/  You will be looking for the AVCam and AVCamDemo sample applications, I believe.

Comment: @Brad Larson - Good heavens! Enough sample code to keep me happy for a good while. Thanks Brad!

Comment: @Daniel Hi, sir, could you pls send me a copy of that sample code? tangqiaoboy<at>gmail.com . Thanks very much.

Comment: If you're going to set the exposure too, make sure you do it after you set the focus.  For some reason doing it the other way around causes problems in my projects.

Comment: @Deniel  Hi  sir Can you send me code on my email id vipul_mehta0024@yahoo.co.in Thank you so much in Advance

Comment: @Daniel, I cannot see focus rectangle with this code snippet. Can you see it?

Comment: not going in if ([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported] this if condition in my iPod , why?

Comment: i have an issue, flash is continuous in iPhone5 , have you faced this issue?

Comment: is it possible to catch focus finish?